# A car pushing a bike and then stops, what happens to the bike?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Does that a) not effect the bike? b) give it a final little push. c) push the bike to the ground as if the bike was on top of the car?

I'm asking that because I'm having an argument on Youtube as I made a video about a [scene in a movie](https://youtu.be/G0q2q8BoQt4) where someone driving a car fast and pushing someone riding a bike in front of them and the car suddenly stops resulting in the bike falling into the lake according to the movie logic which I thought doesn't make any sense. People started attacking me in the comments saying that was not a mistake. So that's why this is important to me and I need your help. Thanks

Comment: To me, at least, the question does  not make sense. The title asks one thing the simple answer being the bike continues on with an initial velocity equal to what it was just before the car stopped (Newton's first law). The supposed answers (a) through (c) seem unrelated to the question in the title. Perhaps you can make this clearer before it is voted to close the question as being too vague.

Comment: It might actually help if you linked to the scene in question, since it's unclear from your description what actually happens in the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Newton's second law:
$$F=ma$$
where $F$ is the net force acting on an object, $m$ is the mass of the object, and $a$ is the acceleration of the object.

As the car is pushing on the bike (not sure how this works) it applies a force and will accelerate it (ignoring any resistive forces like friction, drag, etc.). Once the car stops (or even slows down) it no longer is in contact with the bike (I think, once again I don't know how the car is exactly pushing on the bike) so there is no force acting on the bike anymore. This means the acceleration will drop to $0$ and the bike will continue at a constant velocity (once again, ignoring the effects of other forces).

I don't understand your third possibility, and I haven't seen the video, so I could be wrong if I have misunderstood the system.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I apologize if my question was unclear.
I uploaded the scene on youtube I don't know if thats allowed on the site
https://youtu.be/G0q2q8BoQt4 is this physically accurate?

Comment: @FadyNewaccount yeah it looks like the car just backs off. When he goes into the lake I don't even see the car.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! :)

Comment: @FadyNewaccount Please upvote any answers you find useful and mark answers as accepted for future readers.